# 4 MySQL Tables To Match a Search Variable and List Results from

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, joomla3.1

I'm building a public PHP function which will be used to Search for specific items on my website.

The search module contains 3 fields:

```
- Keyword (text field)
- Location (drop-down menu)
- Category (drop-down menu)
```

The tables look like this:

"items" Table:

```
id |  name  |  alias  |  desc   | short_desc | published | category_id
int| varchar| varchar | varchar |   varchar  | tinyint(1)|     int
example:
3  |  item1 |  item1  |  ditem  |   sditem   |    1      |      1
```

"item_location" Table:

```
item_id    | location_id
    int    |    int      
example:
     3     |     2
```

"categories" Table:

```
id |   name   |  published 
int|   txt    |  tinyint(1)
example:
3  | screen   |     1
4  | mouse    |     1
6  | trackpad |     1
```

"translation" Table:

```
id | ref_id| ref_table | ref_field  |     value      | original_text | published
int|   int |  varchar  |  varchar   |      txt       |      txt      | tinyint(1)
example:
13 |   3   |   items   |   name     | translated txt | original txt  |     1
24 |   3   |   items   | short_desc | translated txt | original txt  |     1
35 |   3   |   items   |    desc    | translated txt | original txt  |     1
```

The key column between these tables is:
items "id" = item_location "item_id" = translation "ref_id"

Now I have a working Public PHP Function which list matched items with search criterion if the visitor used English website interface, hereunder:

```
public static function searchItem ($keyword, $locationId, $categoryId)
{
    $db     = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query  = "SELECT d.* FROM #__items d ";

    $locationId = (int)$locationId;
    $categoryId = (int)$categoryId;

    if($locationId > 0)
    {
        $query .= "INNER JOIN  #__item_location l ON d.id = l.item_id ";
    }

    $query .= "WHERE d.published = 1 ";

    if($keyword != '')
    {
     $query .="AND (";
     $query .="d.name LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
     $query .="OR d.short_desc LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
     $query .="OR d.desc LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
     $query .=") ";
    }

    if($locationId > 0)
    {
        $query .= "AND l.location_id = " . $locationId . " ";
    }

    if($categoryId > 0)
    {
        $query .= "AND d.category_id = " . $categoryId . " ";
    }

    $query .= "ORDER BY d.ordering ASC";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $items = $db->loadAssocList();

    if($db->getErrorNum())
    {
        //JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Now I'm trying to accomplish the same code above, however, in this case "translation" Table shall be searchable to get the right match from it when visitors use non-English website interface. I tried to do it by this code:

```
public static function searchItem ($keyword, $locationId, $categoryId)
{
    $noneng = JFactory::getLanguage()->isNON_ENG();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query  = "SELECT d.* FROM #__items d ";

    $locationId = (int)$locationId;
    $categoryId = (int)$categoryId;

    if($locationId > 0)
    {
    $query .= "INNER JOIN  #__item_location l ON d.id = l.item_id ";
    }

    $query .= "WHERE d.published = 1 ";

// Code modified by myself
if($keyword != '')
{
  if($noneng == true) //to check page language if non english is used then apply the following 
   {
   $query .= "INNER JOIN #__translation 2 ON d.id = 2.ref_id ";
   $query .= "WHERE ";
   $query .= "( 2.ref_table = 'items' ";
   $query .= "AND 2.ref_field = 'name' ";
   $query .= "AND 2.value LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
   $query .= ") ";

   $query .= "OR ( ";
       $query .= "2.ref_table = 'items' ";
       $query .= "AND 2.ref_field = 'desc' ";
   $query .= "AND 2.value LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
   $query .= ") ";

   $query .= "OR ( ";
   $query .= "2.ref_table = 'items' ";
   $query .= "AND 2.ref_field = 'short_desc' ";
   $query .= "AND 2.value LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
   $query .= ") ";
   }
   else
   {
   $query .= "AND (";
   $query .= "d.name LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
   $query .= "OR d.short_desc LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
   $query .= "OR d.desc LIKE " . $db->quote("%" . $keyword . "%") . " ";
   $query .= ") ";
       }
    }

    if($locationId > 0)
    {
        $query .= "AND l.location_id = " . $locationId . " ";
    }

    if($categoryId > 0)
    {
        $query .= "AND d.category_id = " . $categoryId . " ";
    }

    $query .= "ORDER BY d.ordering ASC";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $items  = $db->loadAssocList();

    if($db->getErrorNum())
    {
        //JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Now when someone used english interface it works fine, but when non english is used an error showed up.

Please help me to list non english results from "items" table but with their matched translated text from "translation" table.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between languages in your translations table?

Comment: the error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN #_translation 2 ON d.id = 2.ref_id WHERE ( 2.ref_ta' at line 1

Comment: When I switch the the last URL parameter from lang=en to lang=ar. So only Arabic language in translation table.